# Google DFP: How to get delivery report for multiple orders

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-dfp, google-python-api

I have integrated Google's DFP API(python) to get data from the DFP Network using a service account.

The following is my report job.

```
values = [{
    'key': 'id',
    'value': {
        'xsi_type': 'NumberValue',
        'value': order_id # order_id is passed when the method is called eg: '12345678'
    }
}]
# Create statement object to filter for an order.
filter_statement = {'query': 'WHERE ORDER_ID = :id',
                    'values': values}

# Create report job.
report_job = {
    'reportQuery': {
        'dimensions': ['ORDER_ID', 'ORDER_NAME', 'LINE_ITEM_ID','LINE_ITEM_NAME', 'CREATIVE_ID',
                       'CREATIVE_NAME', 'PLACEMENT_NAME'],
        'dimensionAttributes': ['ORDER_TRAFFICKER', 'ORDER_START_DATE_TIME',
                                'ORDER_END_DATE_TIME'],
        'statement': filter_statement,
        'columns': ['AD_SERVER_IMPRESSIONS', 'AD_SERVER_CLICKS',
                    'TOTAL_LINE_ITEM_LEVEL_IMPRESSIONS'],
        'dateRangeType': 'CUSTOM_DATE',
        'startDate': {'year': start_date.year, 'month': start_date.month,
                      'day': start_date.day
                      },
        'endDate': {'year': end_date.year, 'month': end_date.month,
                    'day': end_date.day
                    }
        }
}
```

This code will download the delivery report for a particular order id.

Is there a way to download delivery report for a list of orders?

[Reference](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-publishers/docs/reporting)